# Ошибка function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

db.php

```
<?php
class Dbh {
private $servername;
private $username;
private $password;
private $dbname;
private $charset;

public function connect() {
$this->servername = 'localhost';
$this->username = 'root';
$this->password = 'exh05t9a';
$this->dbname = 'hash';
$this->charset = 'utf8';

try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dpo;
} catch (PDOExeption $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: ".$e->getMessage();
}
}
}
?>
```

password.php

```
<?php

class Password extends Dbh {
public function getUserPassword() {
    $stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT password FROM users");
    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $password = $row['password'];
        return $password;
    }
}
}
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы с БД выводил пароль, пишет:
**Call to a member function query() on a non-object in W:\domains\hash\password.php on line 5**

Строка 5: **$stmt = $this->connect()->query("SELECT password FROM users");**

Comment: И на каждый вызов `$this->connect()` будет создаваться новое подключение к БД?

Comment: @u_mulder а как сделать, чтобы подключение было один раз тогда? .-.

Comment: Проверить, не установлено ли оно ранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в функции `connect()` возвращается переменная которой не существует `$dpo`, в то время как вы, видимо, хотели вернуть `$pdo`